# Fiducial.yml data field

Tags: ros, pose, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using fiducial.yml to get information about chesboard in test image.
But what does the "data" field stand for? I can not find information about fiducial.yml files fields anywhere.

Myzhar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9800/fiducial.yml-data-field/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2011-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume your question is about the tod_training package, right? I have added that tag to your question. Perhaps this answers your question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/289/does-tod_training-in-object_recognition-require

http://answers.ros.org/question/504/physical-setup-for-collecting-tod_training-data

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0